# Why would I get 2 different API responses from a staging and production environment in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rocketpants

So I'm querying an api in rails 4.2 with limit and offset parameters, and I get 2 different responses in staging and production environments - production errors out.  Do you have any idea why it would work in one environment but not the other?  Below are the logs.  I'm using the rocket_pants gem for the api.  How would I approach debugging something like this?

**Staging response:**

```
2015-01-31T01:42:41.650830+00:00 app[web.2]: Processing by Api::V1::KitesController#index as 
2015-01-31T01:42:41.650902+00:00 app[web.2]:   Parameters: {"limit"=>"10", "offset"=>"0", "version"=>"1"}
2015-01-31T01:42:42.970394+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 200 OK in 1319ms
```

**Production response:**

```
015-01-31T01:45:30.290621+00:00 app[web.2]: Started GET "/1/kites?limit=10&offset=0" for 120.131.46.189 at 2015-01-31 01:45:30 +0000
2015-01-31T01:45:30.293135+00:00 app[web.2]:   Parameters: {"limit"=>"10", "offset"=>"0", "version"=>"1"}
2015-01-31T01:45:30.292819+00:00 app[web.2]: Processing by Api::V1::KitesController#index as 
2015-01-31T01:45:31.219974+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/1/kites?limit=10&offset=0" host=kites.herokuapp.com request_id=3ca59d79-bf90-41e9-a828-ba8bd5d5b0c6 fwd="120.131.46.189" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=922ms status=500 bytes=581
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196390+00:00 app[web.2]: Exception occured: NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for #<Hash:0x007f03d6ec5320>
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196402+00:00 app[web.2]: Exception backtrace:
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196659+00:00 app[web.2]: => /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rocket_pants-1.9.2/lib/rocket_pants/controller/respondable.rb:129:in `respond_with_object_and_type'
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196699+00:00 app[web.2]: => /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rocket_pants-1.9.2/lib/rocket_pants/controller/respondable.rb:134:in `resource'
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196454+00:00 app[web.2]: => /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rocket_pants-1.9.2/lib/rocket_pants/controller/caching.rb:69:in `cache_key_for'
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196494+00:00 app[web.2]: => /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rocket_pants-1.9.2/lib/rocket_pants/controller/caching.rb:55:in `etag_for'
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196534+00:00 app[web.2]: => /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rocket_pants-1.9.2/lib/rocket_pants/controller/caching.rb:117:in `cache_response'
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196570+00:00 app[web.2]: => /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rocket_pants-1.9.2/lib/rocket_pants/controller/caching.rb:130:in `post_process_exposed_object'
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196773+00:00 app[web.2]: => /app/app/controllers/api/v1/clinical_trials_controller.rb:22:in `index'
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196737+00:00 app[web.2]: => /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rocket_pants-1.9.2/lib/rocket_pants/controller/respondable.rb:155:in `exposes'
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196808+00:00 app[web.2]: => /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
2015-01-31T01:45:31.196842+00:00 app[web.2]: => /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
```

Answer (score 1):

If by responses you mean what you see showing up in the log files, different environments have different default logging levels.

Here are two links that may be helpful:

- http://uplifted.net/programming/debugging-rails-errors-on-heroku/
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

Comment: Thanks this helped me figure it out!

Comment: What was the actual issue ? could u please explain how u fixed it.